# Why spring.sql.init.mode and spring.sql.init.platform are not throwing an error for missing sql scripts for MySQL?

Tags: java, spring-boot

For Spring Boot **3.1.1**

About dependencies is declared:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the `src/main/resources` exists only the following:

```
src/main/resources
   application.properties
   application-mysql.properties
```

Observe there are **no** `.sql` files. The `application.properties` file contains

```
spring.profiles.active=mysql,cache
```

The `application-mysql.properties` file - that must be used for runtime because the `mysql` profile was declared and the `application-{profile}.properties` pattern is applied - contains:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192....
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=<something>

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.platform=mysql
```

The connection is accomplished and some CRUD operations is executed at peace but ...

*but is expected* to receive an error/exception at startup due the following:

- `spring.sql.init.mode=always` because there is **no** an *in-memory* database such `h2` and `MySQL` is used instead, therefore some *sql scripts* must be executed.
- `spring.sql.init.platform=mysql` is expected to find the `schema-mysql.sql` and `data-mysql.sql` files at `src/main/resources`, it according with the `schema-${platform}.sql` and `data-${platform}.sql` patterns respectively

Now because the `schema-mysql.sql` and `data-mysql.sql` does **not** exist at `src/main/resources` is expected an error, but it does **not** happen. Why? ... Same situation if is declared

```
spring.sql.init.platform=mysqlabc
```

I am assuming some *Application Property* is missing

Consider the use the `MySQL` and not `H2` for pre-production purposes.

Comment: Both scripts are optional, so no error will be thrown.

Comment: Interesting it is not mentioned at - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts

Comment: You can see it in the implementation. Neither is required, you can only have a `schema.sql`, or a `data.sql` or a `schema-mysql.sql` and generic `data.sql` all sorts of combinations are possible, then what should be required? Although a warning in the logs could be an improvement if init is enabled but no sql files are actually found.

Comment: I see, I am going to create an issue on Github, a new Application Property would be added, it to enable or not to thrown an exception if the expected sql scripts are not found ... of of course for backwards compatibility it should be _false_ as default